# Making a case statement when a count condition is bigger than 0

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to make a pretty complex SQL query, which results in 0/1 or TRUE/FALSE depending on my conditions.

Idea is that I have a customer table, and then I want to make a couple of checks in different tables, and then if either is true, then we return TRUE, and if not, FALSE:

I was thinking to do this with CASE. See example below:

```
select 
    case 
        ((select count(*) from boughtleads bl where bl.customerid = cu.id)>0)
            then 'TRUE' 
            else 'FALSE' 
    end 

from customers cu
left join leadagents la on la.customerid = cu.id
where cu.vatnumber = '30218124'
```

This returns:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near '>'.
```

My challenge is then. First of all, the above query fails for some reason, my other problem is I can't use an OR.

My ideal pseudocode would be something like:

```
select 
    case 
        (
            ((select count(*) from boughtleads bl where bl.customerid = cu.id)>0)
            OR
            ((select count(*) from leadnotifications ln where ln.leadagentid = la.id)>))
                then 'TRUE' 
                else 'FALSE' 
    end 

from customers cu
left join leadagents la on la.customerid = cu.id
where cu.vatnumber = '30218124'
```

Any ideas on how to attack this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing `when`:

```
select (case when (select count(*) from boughtleads bl where bl.customerid = cu.id) > 0
             then 'TRUE' 
             else 'FALSE' 
        end)
from customers cu left join
     leadagents la
     on la.customerid = cu.id
where cu.vatnumber = '30218124';
```

That said, from a performance perspective it is better to write such conditions using `exists`:

```
select (case when exists (select 1 from boughtleads bl where bl.customerid = cu.id)
             then 'TRUE' 
             else 'FALSE' 
        end)
from customers cu left join
     leadagents la
     on la.customerid = cu.id
where cu.vatnumber = '30218124'
```

The `count(*)` version has to find *all* matching rows in `boughtleads`.  The `exists` version can stop at the first match.

Comment: Damn, of course. Thanks a lot! Do you have a hint towards the "OR" statement? :)

Comment: @LarsHoldgaard . . . Just use `or exists ()`.